# Ways to work around the Android workManager 15 minute minimum interval?

Tags: java, android

The game I am working on is a missile-oriented GPS-based combat game on Android. The app checks every 15 minutes to see if the user is under attack by any other players, and if so, sends them a notification that they are under attack. Currently, because of the minimum 15 minute interval, the app sends these notifications either too late or not at all. What I need to do is alter this so that somehow, some way, the app checks the "under attack" status of the user more often than 15 minutes. Every minute or every 30 seconds would be ideal.

here is the doWork() method which starts the notification check:

```
    {
        if(!MainActivity.GetRunning())
        {
            Utilities.DebugLog(context, "AlertService", "Main activity not running. Firing notification service handler.");
            NotificationServiceHandler handler = new NotificationServiceHandler(context);
            handler.Start();
        }

        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`WorkManager` is not a suitable tool for what you wish to do. You will need to use a foreground service and your own in-process timing engine (e.g., `ScheduledExecutorService`). That will not work for very long before Doze mode and other power-saving measures take effect, but hopefully your games are only an hour or so long.

Comment: The game runs continuously, unfortunately. There are no rounds that "end."

Comment: @TheBiscuit: Then you are going to have problems. Doing network I/O every 30 seconds, continuously, is terrible for battery life. As a result, Google, device manufacturers, and many users will be fighting you every step of the way.

Comment: Would it be possible to ping the app from the server end, starting the process precisely when the player became "under attack" instead of just continuously checking to see if the player is under attack? 

Also, what about running a loop in NotificationServiceHandler that executes the check once every minute for 15 minutes, dies, then gets started again the next time workManager is scheduled to start?

Comment: @TheBiscuit It would be advisable to use `Backend + Push Notification`, any type of workaround on a device with that short level of interval for i/o tasks will heavily impact the device & the battery.

Comment: @TheBiscuit: "Would it be possible to ping the app from the server end, starting the process precisely when the player became "under attack" instead of just continuously checking to see if the player is under attack?" -- using something like Firebase Cloud Messaging, yes. That is the preferable solution, from the standpoint of the device and the user.

Answer (score 0):

Hej theBiscuit,

instead of using `WorkManager`, you could set up an `AlarmManager` to wake up the app and check for attacks.

If you want to do it while the app is running, a CountDownTimer could help for short periods of time.